# Programmatically get java proposals for eclipse bundle

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, eclipse-plugin

I tried various combinations for my problem but of no use.

**Problem**

I am developing one eclipse osgi bundle to correct java source code automatically.  I am able to get java project object and a class object inside it which I want to correct.  Every time I try to collect java code proposals as I put one test file which can be corrected (like duplicate imports)

I always get errors similar to below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.getImageDescriptorRegistry(JavaPlugin.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalCollector.<init>(CompletionProposalCollector.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalCollector.<init>(CompletionProposalCollector.java:157)
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.  Here is my code snippet:

```
....
CompletionProposalCollector collectorPrjTemp= new CompletionProposalCollector(javaProject); // this line throws error
IJavaCompletionProposal[] prjProposals = collectorPrjTemp.getJavaCompletionProposals();
System.out.println("prjProposals == "+prjProposals.length);
....
```

**Edit on 28-Jul**

Now when I included dependency of org.eclipse.jdt.ui above NullPointer error goes away.  But now receiving below error

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 2 2015-07-28 13:07:37.926
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.ui".
!STACK 0

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.install(ASTProvider.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.<init>(ASTProvider.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.getASTProvider(JavaPlugin.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SharedASTProvider.getAST(SharedASTProvider.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.AssistContext.getASTRoot(AssistContext.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.ReorgCorrectionsSubProcessor.removeImportStatementProposals(ReorgCorrectionsSubProcessor.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.QuickFixProcessor.process(QuickFixProcessor.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.QuickFixProcessor.getCorrections(QuickFixProcessor.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.JavaCorrectionProcessor$SafeCorrectionCollector.safeRun(JavaCorrectionProcessor.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.JavaCorrectionProcessor$SafeCorrectionProcessorAccess.run(JavaCorrectionProcessor.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.JavaCorrectionProcessor$SafeCorrectionProcessorAccess.process(JavaCorrectionProcessor.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.JavaCorrectionProcessor.collectCorrections(JavaCorrectionProcessor.java:468)
```

**Update - 29-Jul**

Now I am trying to create workbench object via command

```
    WorkbenchAdvisor advisor=new WorkbenchAdvisor(){
        public String getInitialWindowPerspectiveId(){
          return "org.eclipse.rap.junit.runtime.emptyPerspective";
        }
      };
    //Display display = Display.getCurrent (); // did not worked, gives null
    //Display display = Display.getDefault (); // did not worked, gives null
    Display display = PlatformUI.getDisplay (); // did not worked, gives null
    PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, advisor);
```

When I tried below code

```
Display display = new Display ();
```

then got below error:

```
No context available outside of the request processing
```

Please read comments between myself and greg for my tries.  Any help/clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this in an Eclipse plugin running in Eclipse? It looks like the JavaPlugin has not been started which would happen if you try to use it outside of Eclipse.

Comment: I am running this inside eclipse.  And this code is running fine "IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("Sample");", do I need to do any thing specific for JavaPlugin

Comment: Hi greg-449,  Still question from you helps me,  I am now one step ahead.  Actually I need to add jdt.ui plugin as required plugin that I get information from this place (http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/67141/).  And now I am into new error - "Workbench not created yet.  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.".  Now looking into that.  Please let me know if any of you has any pointer.

Comment: Workbench has not been created yet happens if you run very early in Eclipse startup (or you are not running in Eclipse or an Eclipse RCP).

Comment: Oh.  What to do?  I tried to put Thread.sleep for even 10 seconds in my code but no help.  Tried including more bundles but again of no use.  Also tried start-up level in eclipse but same result, please suggest.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly where this code is running. Is it an Eclipse plugin? What triggers the code to run?

Comment: Here are details: I created project as eclipse plugin, there is one class that extends BundleActivator and from there flow starts, every time I select manifest file and Run as OSGi framework from eclipse itself which opens up console and shows up output.

Comment: You need to use 'Run As > Eclipse Application'

Comment: I don't know what wrong I am doing,  I tried three combinations (1) Run project as OSGi framework (2) Run as Eclipse Application (as Product) (3)  Run as Eclipse Application (as Workbench).......... In #1 option I receive "Workbench has not......" error but able to find two of my projects (Hello and Sample), then #2 opens new window and do not find any project, lastly #3 only identifies Hello project which I am running but throwing same Workbench close error same as #1.  User greg-449, if you feel ok I can mail you separately for your suggestion, my id is shailendravermag@gmail.com

Comment: Run as > Eclipse Application will start a new Eclipse with a **new workspace** so you need to add projects to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to create one handler from where I get ExecutionEvent Object and then I trigger my flow from that point and get object of Workbench, ResourcePlugin, Workspace and Project/JavaProject.

And at last I am able to get proposals which I need.  So if you need workbench object you need UI.

Answer (score 0):

To test an Eclipse plugin you use 'Run As > Eclipse Application'.

For a plugin this will start a new instance of Eclipse with a new workspace (which will be empty initially). You will have to create test projects in this workspace to work with.

The 'Run > Run Configurations' menu will show you the location of the test workspace in the configuration entry for your application.

Comment: :( Still same error.  What I am doing - Running my Hello project in which there is code to refer a same or other project in which there is one Test.java for which I need java proposals.  Now if I run as Eclipse Appl then I need workbench object and add Hello project programatically to it.  But now getting error as "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name" when trying to load project as "project = workspace.getRoot().getFolder(Path.fromOSString("/Hello")).getProject();"

Comment: `getFolder` must have a least a project name and a folder name. Just use `project = workspace.getRoot().getProject("Hello")` if you want the project called 'Hello'

Comment: ok, now program says Project loaded but when I print all project list from workspace it prints only 1 as "RemoteSystemsTempFiles".  Basically my project Hello is not available via workspace.  I am running it as a product Eclipse Appl which opens new eclipse instance.

Comment: As I said you get a new workspace, you must create projects in the new workspace for testing. You can only access your existing workspace by installing the plugin in your main Eclipse.

Comment: ok, I managed to do that and guess what !! All three options are giving same error :( "Workbench has not been created yet" is really killing me.  By the way I am making this plugin bcoz I want a framework which can analysis problems in my java code and can give me suggestion to correct code as well programmatically. Is there any such framework other than eclipse.  It looks there are tons of hacks I need to make for this project to work.  Really upset